# How to call onChange function when URL on webView changes MAUI

Tags: c#, mvvm, .net-6.0, inotifypropertychanged, maui

I have a binding set on the webView source from my ViewModel. In the beginning, the source is being redirected correctly, but when URL of the webView changes I want to call a function OnAuthUrlChanged, which is not happening. how do I do that

xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <WebView        
       Source="{Binding AuthUrl, Mode=TwoWay}"            
       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

ViewModel

```
public partial class LoginViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public LoginViewModel(IConfiguration config)
    {
        this.configuration = config;
        AuthUrl = CreateAuthUrl();
    } 

   [ObservableProperty]       
   private UrlWebViewSource? authUrl;

   private UrlWebViewSource CreateAuthUrl()
   {
      var result = new UrlWebViewSource();            
      result.Url = configuration.GetSection("Connections").GetValue<string>("LoginUrl");            
      return result;

   }

   // I want to hit this function when url changes
   partial void OnAuthUrlChanged(UrlWebViewSource? value)
   {
      Console.WriteLine($"Name is about to change to {value}");
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to be notified when your URL changes? I see you are inheriting ObservableObject in your ViewModel, are you using Community Toolkits?

Answer (score 0):

It is working. You just expect it to happen when you first set it.
And that is not how it works.

Add a button, make it change it to something else, and you will see that you will hit it.

It needs to be set to something, and get set to something else, for this to shoot.